# Remove hiss from audio

Tags: noise

I have a stereo track that was recorded in a dslr camera using a lavalier mic. The right channel has all the voice information (along with a lot of noise) and the left channel has only noise. 
I tried to invert the left channel to see if it would cancel the noise from the other channel, but it didn't help. But I don't know if I did it right.
Do you think there is some way I can use the noise information from the left channel to help me clean the channel that has the actual information I need?
If it helps, I know this noise comes from the camera. It's a constant hiss in both channels.

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on the type of noise. If it's white noise, it's not going to help at all.

Answer (score 3):

To fully discard the option of the method you tried make sure that before you invert the phase of the left channel you bring both channels to the center field; then you invert the phase and judge if its working or not.

However, your best bet will be an audio repair/restore plugin (or hardware), perhaps [Izotope - RX](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/repair-and-edit/rx.html) de-noiser, spectral repair or [Waves x or z denoiser](http://www.waves.com/plugins/noise-reduction-restoration#sort:path~type~order=.default-order~number~asc|views:view=list-view|paging:currentPage=0|paging:number=20).

> "Do you think there is some way I can use the noise information from the left channel to help me clean the channel that has the actual information I need?"

Yes, if the noise is exactly the same as the noise in the right channel, you can feed the left channel's noise to these de-noiser plugins so they "learn" the noise, and then they will apply their algorithms to remove the "learned" noise from the audio you want to clean.